# IconButton Click Affect not covering the whole Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```dart
Container(
  height: 65,
  width: 65,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: IconButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      print('clickedddd');
    },
    icon: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed_sharp),
  ),
),
```

I have this Container and when I click the IconButton, the ripple affect does not cover the whole area, is there any way that I can make it to the same size to the parent container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    height: 65,
    width: 65,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    child: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed_sharp),
  ),
)
```

Wrap your container with the Inkwell and replace the icon button with icon widget.

Answer (score 1):

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    height: 65,
    width: 65,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    child: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed_sharp)
  ),
),
```

Use GestureDetector to wrap your widget and you can add different properties such as onTap, onDoubleTap, and onLongPress.